# NSDate loses and hour when adding a month during DST change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate

When trying to add a month using the suggested 'correct' method on all the stackoverflow questions I can find, the date I get back always loses an hour due to DST.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *component = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[component setDay:29];
[component setMonth:3];
[component setYear:2015];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:component];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);

NSDateComponents *monthComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
monthComponent.month = 1;

NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:monthComponent toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate);
```

The output of this code is:

Date: 2015-03-29 00:00:00 +0000

newDate: 2015-04-28 23:00:00 +0000

How can I add a month across a DST change and keep the time at midnight?

Thanks for any help.

**Example in response to gnasher729 below:**

In the example the first two dates would be set at midnight and the second two would be 23:00. What would be the best practice to implement something like this while keeping all the outputted dates to the desired midnight time?

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *initialDateComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[initialDateComponent setDay:29];
[initialDateComponent setMonth:1];
[initialDateComponent setYear:2015];
NSDate *date = [gregorian initialDateComponent];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);

NSDateComponents *monthComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
monthComponent.month = 1;
monthComponent.hour = 0;
NSMutableArray *eventAlarmDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int numberOfRepeatingMonths = 4;
for(int x = 0; 0 < numberOfRepeatingMonths; x++) {
   date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:monthComponent toDate:date options:0];
  [eventAlarmDate addObject:date];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking us how to introduce a bug in your code.

The result is correct. Adding one month during a DST change will and must add one hour more or one hour less than full days.

NSDate *always* displays its date in UTC, which is British time without DST correction. The date calculated is *with* DST corrections, and it depends on your location. If you are in India, midnight is at 5:30 am UTC (or 18:30 pm UTC on the previous day, not sure).

Comment: So there is no obvious way to continually increment throughout the year while keeping the time at midnight.

For example if someone wanted to repeat a calendar event at midnight every month from the original date set?

see example in question edit above.

Comment: In the example I have added above the first two dates would be set at midnight and the second two would be 23:00. What would be the best solution to set them all to the desired midnight time?

Comment: That 23:00 _is_ midnight. Imagine you are sitting in New York and running your code. Time in New York is five hours behind UTC. So midnight in New York is at 5:00am in the morning in UTC. In London, midnight is at 0:00am during the winter, and in spring when you set your clock forward, midnight is at 23:00 pm.

Comment: I understand what you mean about NSDate using UTC as the it's reference point. But surely if they are gonna make an effort to return the local time including calculations for DST around the world, they would also include a method to transition from one day at a set time to the next day at the same set time accounting for any change due to DST. As from a users perspective when they refer to midnight during spring or during winter they are referring to 00:00am in the current local time?

Comment: NSLog displays UTC. The results that you are getting are _correct_ as I said from the very start.

Comment: Ok I think I see my confusion now. Sorry for ping ponging back and forth. So as a quick follow on question, how would I NSLog the returned UTC formatted with a chosen time zone ie. London or New York? @gnasher729